# Perform multiple summation

Tags: math, nested-loops

I am trying to perform multiple summation in a code C++, but I don't know how to write a code to perform multiple for's .
$$\sum_{S_1=\pm1}...\sum_{S_N=\pm1}(\Pi_{i=1}^{N-1}e^{S_iS_{i+1})}$$
As you can see if I try to implement this manually I should write N for's and 1 more for the big pi, so how can I reduce the N for's so as I only need to 3, one indicating the number of for that I want to repeat, another for the summation and the last one for the multiplication.
Plz help

The only think that goes to my mind is:
for S1 = [-1,1]
for S2 = [-1,1]
.
.
.
.
for SN = [-1,1]

Answer (score 0):

Though this isn't really what you asked, you can simplify

```
\Pi_{i=1}^{N-1}e^{S_iS_{i+1})
```

to

```
e^(\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} S_iS_{i+1})
```

so you only do the exponentiation once for each set of S_i values.

I think your question relates to having a variable number of nested for loops. A naive way of handling this is to code a function for each of the possible values of N, but this is verbose and open to criticism.

How I would tackle this would be to use the bits of an unsigned integer U to represent the signed S_i in the following way. I haven't tested this so it comes without warranty, but hopefully you get the gist of it.

```
S_i = (U & (1 << i)) >> i // Get the ith bit

S_i = 2*S_i - 1 // Convert to -1, 1
```

This way you only need 2 for loops.

```
bigsum = 0

for (U = 0; U < (1 << N); U++)

  exponent = 0

  for (i=1; i<N; i++)

    exponent += S_iS_{i+1}
   
  bigsum += e^exponent
```

You will need to use an integer type with more than maxN bits.

Comment: I suspect there's a faster way to get the result with a different algorithm, but I think this is the approach you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon notes:

```
\Pi_{i=1}^{N-1}e^{S_iS_{i+1})
```

can be expressed as:

```
e^(\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} S_iS_{i+1})
```

We're evaluating this at every possible assignment of `S_i` for all i, and summing the results. Note that the sum `\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} S_iS_{i+1}` represents the number of matching consecutive values in the sequence `S_i` minus the number of non-matching consecutive values. As an example, `[1, 1, -1, 1]` produces `(1*1 + 1*-1 + -1*1) = -1`. There is one matching consecutive pair `(1, 1)` and two non-matching consecutive pairs `(1, -1)` and `(-1, 1)`, yielding the same result `1 - 2 = -1`.

The number of matching consecutive pairs `A` in a given sequence can be calculated from the number of non-matching ones `B`: `A = N - 1 - B`. This means from `B` we can calculate the value of the exponent: `A - B = N - 1 - 2*B`.

The value `B` can only take on the values in the interval `[0, N)`. So, instead of iterating over all possible assignments, calculating each `B`, we can try to do something smarter. We can try to calculate how many assignments produce a given `B`, iterating over each possible value of `B`, and skip the actual assignments. Note that the relative position of each non-matching pair doesn't matter, nor the number of consecutive matching pairs. As an example: `[1, 1, -1, 1, -1]` has the same number of matching/non-matching and thus the same sum as `[-1, 1, -1, 1, 1]` and `[1, -1, 1, 1, -1]`. What we can do is group consecutive matching `S_i` into chunks: `[(1, 1), (-1), (1), (-1)]`. Each sequence of `S_i` that has `B = k-1` non-matching consecutive pairs can be partitioned into `k` uniform parts like this.

Now we need to calculate for `N`, how many ways can we create uniform ordered k-partitions, for `k` in `[1, N)`. This is your standard [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) combinatorics problem; we just need to choose `k-1` from `N-2`. Just to be entirely clear:

```
x choose y = nck(x, y) = x! / ((x-y)! * y!)
```

One small detail we can't forget: in each of these partitions, we claim there are uniform parts of consecutive `-1`s or `1`s. Given two adjacent parts can't both contain `1`s nor both `-1`s, e.g. `[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1)]`, the choice of values for the first part determines the assignment for the rest. That means the first part offers our only degree freedom, and that for any partition we have to consider two options: the one that starts with a `1` part, and the one that starts with `-1`. So in effect, the count of assignments with `B` non-matching consecutive pairs (`B+1` parts) will be `2 * nck(N-2, B)`.

Now, for each value of `B`, we can calculate the number of corresponding assignments, multiply by the exponential, and calculate the value of the overall expression.

```
2*\sum_{B=0}^{N-2}nck(N-2, B)e^(N-1-2*B)
```

The `nck(N-2, B)` calculation can be done in `O(1)` time by building off the  calculation from the previous loop iteration, using only a single multiplication and division to calculate the new value. The same tactic can be used for the computation of the exponential. This means the whole calculation can be done in `O(n)` time.

**Update**

After reflecting back on this problem, I see that there's an even cleaner and faster closed-form solution. Taking the summation from the final step above, we can simplify using the binomial formula, and arrive at:

```
2*e^{3-N}*(1+e^2)^{N-2}
```

This can then be evaluated in logarithmic time using exponentiation by squaring, resulting in an `O(log(n))` time solution overall.